# What is the name of cellular respiration that Prokayotic cells use?

Tags: cellular-respiration, prokaryotic-cells

Eukaryotic cells use mitochondria using anaerobic or aerobic respiration. Prokayotic cells lack mitochondria but are bacteria. Mitochondria originated from bacteria and can be used in the same way. Bacteria produce ATP the same way that Mitochondria do.

So, what is that kind of cellular respiration called?

Comment: "*Prokayotic cells lack mitochondria but use bacteria instead*" ??

Comment: @Dexter Yes. Here's some extra info.  http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5430/how-do-prokaryotes-perform-cellular-respiration-without-membrane-bound-organelle

Comment: Prokaryotic cells don't 'use' bacteria. Bacteria are prokaryotic cells. Is it some wrong formation of sentence ?

Comment: @Dexter I fixed it.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK7919/).

Comment: I think I figured it out from someone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prokayotic cells use anaerobic respiration.

Glycolysis is the only stage of cellular respiration that does not occur in mitochondria.

The glycolysis process does not need oxygen and uses anaerobic respiration. The other stages require oxygen and use aerobic respiration.